# lodash casting, mapping and picking

Tags: lodash

I have an array of objects that I am simplifying as this:

```
var expenses = [
        {
          arm: "0",
          cat_id: "1",
          crop: {
            crop: "corn",
            id: 1
          },
          crop_id: "1",
          dist: "164.97",
          expense: "Fertilizer",
          id: "1",
          loan_id: "1"
        },
        {
          arm: "20",
          cat_id: "8",
          crop: {
            crop: "corn",
            id: 1
          },
          crop_id: "1",
          dist: "0",
          expense: "Labor",
          id: "8",
          loan_id: "1"
        }
      ];
```

I am trying to end up with this:

```
var expenses = [{
    arm: 0,
    cat_id: 1,
    crop: "corn",
    crop_id: 1,
    dist: 164.97,
    expense: "Fertilizer",
    id: 1,
    loan_id: 1
 },{
    arm: 20,
    cat_id: 6,
    crop: "corn",
    crop_id: 1,
    dist: 0,
    expense: "Labor",
    id: 1,
    loan_id: 1
}];
```

I can get certain pieces in that direction but can't pull it all together without error. I can't find out how to cast the values to float or put crop INSIDE of stub because casted returns all nulls. I currently have this:

```
flattened = _.map(expenses, function(item){
        var crop = item.crop.crop;
        var stub = _.pick(item, [
            'id',
            'loan_id',
            'cat_id',
            'expense',
            'crop_id',
            'arm', 
            'dist'
          ]);
          var casted = _.map(stub, function(i){
            i.crop = crop;
            return i;
          });
          return stub;
      });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem 1: I can't find out how to cast the values to float

This should be easily fixed by using **[parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)**.

e.g.

```
item.dist = parseFloat(item.dist);
```

> Problem 2: put crop INSIDE of stub because casted returns all nulls

Since you're already using lodash, might as well get used to their chaining feature (lazy evaluation).

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/IL0WzSUtmpRtnxtgAWNU?p=preview)**

```
var flattened = _.map(expenses, function(item) {
  item.dist = parseFloat(item.dist);
  return _(item)
    .omit('crop')
    .assign(_.omit(item.crop, 'id'))
    .value();
});
```

The solution above maps the entire expenses array, converting `item.dist` to a floating point value and then flattening the values from the `item.crop` object towards the `item` object with the exception of the `item.crop.id` value.

> Note: In regards to your solution above, using `_.map` in an object
>   results to an array.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt for my own learning purposes based on @ryeballar code.

```
var flattened = _.map(expenses, function(item) {
  return _(item)
    .set('crop', item.crop.crop) // set item.crop
    .set('dist', parseFloat(item.dist)) // set dist as (float)item.dist
    .value();
});
```